# Can I just unsolder a volume control from one device to replace the control on its identical twin?

Tags: soldering

I have two Casio CTK-671 keyboards. One of them (unit A) is dodgy because it outputs a high pitched tone 50% of the time, not reacting to any key press, the other one (unit B) is dodgy because the volume control seems broken. I can slide it all I want, the volume does not change. In some positions only one speaker works, in most others none work, and in one rare position both work.

The volume control is on a separate PCB connected to another PCB by four wires. These wires are soldered onto the PCB's. Is it possible to unsolder the wires of the volume control PCB of unit A and B and swap them such that unit B would have a working volume control?
I am absolutely new to soldering and electronics, so that's why I pose this basic question.
My greatest doubt is about unsoldering the wires from the PCB, is that at all possible?

Comment: Any pointers on why this is downvoted? Can I somehow edit this question such that it suits this stackexchange better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly OK to swap the volume controls since they are identical.  As far as soldering, if you have no experience don't do this swap right now.  Get some experience soldering and unsoldering first.  If you have nothing else to work on, use the bad keyboard as a platform for getting experience.  Find some soldering tutorials on line.  I'm sure you can find Youtube videos to help you.  Once you feel confident, unsolder the volume control on the bad unit first. It won't matter if you mess up that PCB since you are not going to use it.  Then, now having some experience, unsolder the volume control on the good keyboard.  Then solder the good volume control onto the PCB.  Note that a soldering iron for PCBs should be a relatively low wattage, probably around 30 watts.

Comment: Followed instructions, worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough. Try some soldering practice first, on some other dead electronics. Watch some videos on how to do it properly.

Aside from that, the other hint is since the volume boards are on wires, just use a snip to cut the off close to the board. This makes unsoldering the extra ends off the good board easier, and you don't have to unsolder from both keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

if you want fool proof desoldering get something like: [this](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062731&utm_source=Google&utm_medium=PPC&utm_term=2160644&utm_content=Exact&utm_campaign=PLA&cagpspn=pla&gclid=CODm5ZaTwbUCFWd_MAod7HMAAA&gclsrc=ds)

and since you are reusing the part it is also a good idea to get a heat sink like: [this](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2103242) or hackle pliers like: [this will work too.](http://www.flyshack.com/images/items/Midge_Hackle_Pliers.jpg)

I dont mean endorse the RS, but those pictures came up first.

Answer (score 0):

By your description  it sounds like Casio newer meant this item to be repaired as product is too cheap to produce (like 2000s dvd/divx players) thou it's marketed as "Professional Keyboard". I'm judging that based on lack of some cheapish connector that should be used instead of desoldering wires that goes from one module to another

In those cases i personally prefer to use some "tallish" sticker in opposite direction because i often hurries so i'd protect mysellf from switching last-first wire place in crowded space without proper connector keying (key == marker for 1st pin). In my case tweezers or pliers are unnecessary tool but depending on pcb you'd probably need a desoldering pump and some Q-tips (first dry to clean dust, then dipped in alcohol and then dry clean again)

And before you go into desoldering-soldering adventure you could try to clean damn volume pot as these degrades after 5yrs (And these are at least twice that old judging by some weird rewievs http://www.epinions.com/review/pr-Casio_CTK_671_61_Key_Portable_Keyboard/content_120249028228)
It's way simpler if that vol pot is of any quality. If there are push buttons instead i'd only replace them. It's probably little bit more soldering (and searching) but you would do a better job by using more quality ones than originals and they're UNUSED.